# Wordpress show post by page views and limit results

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i already manage to show post by views but i need it to limit the displayed post to a value.

```
 <?php 
$postcnt = 0; query_posts('posts_per_page =>9','&order=desc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=post_views_count');
if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

this is my code.

```
'posts_per_page =>9' isn't working..
```

Comment: You're calling it wrongly. Have a look at the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts The first example under All Posts in a Category shows you the correct way to format your call.

Comment: $postcnt = 0; query_posts('&posts_per_page=2,&order=desc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=post_views_count');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append your parameter to the existing global `$query_string`.

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=5' );
if (have_posts()) : // ....
```

Since you are only using your own custom query string, you should append the value at the end.

```
query_posts( '&order=desc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=post_views_count&posts_per_page=9');
```

You can also use an `array()` to pass in your arguments.

```
$args = array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'posts_per_page' => '9',   
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Yes thanks i already figured it out hehe very similar with your answer hehe i have done this,, $postcnt = 0; query_posts('&posts_per_page=2,&order=desc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=post_views_count');